# Rails 3.2.2 Integrating spree in existing rails application. Migration table name conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have full featured existing Rails 3.2.2 running application. I want to integrate the spree application with it.

I have followed the steps for adding Spree which are given in the Github http://github.com/spree/spree BUT I already have some tables with the same name which Spree has like 'addresses' and 'users'

The migrations are failing because of name conflict. when I tried

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "spree_"
```

It started running all migrations from beginning and prepended spree_ to every table and got in conflict again because original table also get name like spree_addresses.

How should I go ahead for integrating the spree in existing application.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it will be quite tough. You somehow must merge both spree and your apps user models and addresses models to make them compatible.

Easiest would be to start from scratch and install spree. I was in your situation and ended up with a fresh rails app.

Comment: Yes, I have merged the fields in the conflicting tables an made it one. Now its fine. started working on integrating existing app's authentication system with the spree authentication system code...thanks :)